# Retrieving ALL the facet search values - impossible?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

Seems that there is a limit of retrieving only 1000 values per facet from the AzureSearch api.  Is there any way to overcome this?  We just want to run a report listing the values/counts per facet.  We do not need the actual documents returned for this report.

Looks like our only alternative is to query the database, but with all the money we're spending on AzureSearch it's disappointing to not find an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could run multiple queries and filter out the refiner values you have received data for.

1. Run your query as you do today
2. Add a filter to exclude any value you have a count for
3. Continue querying until you have all your data

Note: Traversing results like this is not guaranteed to be 100% accurate. I don't know if that matters to you. Search is not built for the use case you describe here, but databases are.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try count:0 to see if this gives the desired effect you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the count of the [`facet` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#:%7E:text=%22facet%3Dcategory%2Ccount%3A5%22), the default is 10;
`facet=category,count:1000`.

facet=category,count:0 - Will retrieve all